# C programming- Filtering arrays

Tags: c

I'm supposed to filter values below, in between and above a threshold, define and use functions with arrays as arguments. Pass an array as an argument to a function. 
These are the arrays given. I've tried different things with multiple errors.

```
int  lowNumbers[] = { 73,80,96,92,91,64,24,14,42,47,94,88,93,48,35,28,49,64,81, 5,47,
                      22,16,57,56,10,81,91,5 ,19,90,79,6 ,31,55,44,81, 3,75,80,93,69,
                      86,74,72,32,66,16,36,78,63,99,45,14,72,48,89, 3,83,57,43,96,33,
                      20,75,95,64,84,71,70,74,73,43,82,61,77,55,10, 6, 2,94,50,99,10,
                      55,34,39,12,78,7,73,35,32,13,54,45,0,74,18,40};

int highNumbers[] = {  90,129, 91, 62,144,138, 82,142,138, 86,148,116,130, 57,120, 62,
                       76, 75, 79,140, 73, 94,139, 81,122,113,100,121, 62, 86, 85,107,
                      129,119, 79, 84,104,143, 87,111,107, 85,141,143, 62, 92, 64,106,
                      148,147,143, 69,125,125,109, 86,148,137, 66, 61,133, 80, 64, 97,
                       84,123, 57, 94,116,115, 81,138,104, 79, 69,102,118, 64, 61, 99,
                       56, 69,135, 66, 61, 64,108,110,110, 91, 84,108,133,150, 68,109,
                      139, 84, 52, 63 };



#include <stdio.h>
#define ASIZE = 100

void displayintroduction (void);
void filterBelowThreshold(int thres, int src[], int filtered[]);
void filterAboveThreshold (int thres, int sourceAr[], int 
filtered2[]);
void print3Arrays(int filterAboveThreshold, int 
filterBelowThreshold);

int main()
{
displayintroduction ();
int sourceAr[100];
int high_limit;
int low_limt;

int  lowNumbers[] = { 
73,80,96,92,91,64,24,14,42,47,94,88,93,48,35,28,49,64,81, 5,47,
                      22,16,57,56,10,81,91,5 ,19,90,79,6 
,31,55,44,81, 3,75,80,93,69,
                      86,74,72,32,66,16,36,78,63,99,45,14,72,48,89, 
3,83,57,43,96,33,
                      20,75,95,64,84,71,70,74,73,43,82,61,77,55,10, 
6, 2,94,50,99,10,

55,34,39,12,78,7,73,35,32,13,54,45,0,74,18,40};

int highNumbers[] = {  90,129, 91, 62,144,138, 82,142,138, 
86,148,116,130, 57,120, 62,
                       76, 75, 79,140, 73, 94,139, 
81,122,113,100,121, 62, 86, 85,107,
                      129,119, 79, 84,104,143, 87,111,107, 
85,141,143, 62, 92, 64,106,
                      148,147,143, 69,125,125,109, 86,148,137, 66, 
61,133, 80, 64, 97,
                   84,123, 57, 94,116,115, 81,138,104, 79, 
69,102,118, 64, 61, 99,
                       56, 69,135, 66, 61, 64,108,110,110, 91, 
84,108,133,150, 68,109,
                      139, 84, 52, 63 };
int num_1;
scanf("%d",&num_1);

for(int loop = 0; loop< 100;loop++)
{
  if (num_1==1 )
  {
     sourceAr[loop]=lowNumbers[loop];
  }
  else if (num_1 ==2)
  {
      sourceAr[loop] = highNumbers[loop];
  }
  else
  displayintroduction();

}

printf("\n****************************************************");
printf("\nplease enter the upper and lower limit for the array");
scanf("%d%d",&high_limit, &low_limt);
printf("\n****************************************************");

filterBelowThreshold(int low_limt , int sourceAr[], int filtered[])
filterAboveThreshold (int high_limit, int sourceAr[], int 
filtered2[])
print3Arrays(int filterAboveThreshold, int filterBelowThreshold, int 
filtered, int filtered2, int dex , int dex_2, int high_limit, int 
low_limt)
}

void displayintroduction ()
{
printf("**************************************************");
printf("\nthis program  processes and filters arrays from ");
printf("\n holding threshold into the filtered threshold.");
printf("\n the user will be prompted to indicate the  array to be");
printf("\n used. enter'1' for the array 'lowNumbers'" );
printf("\n enter '2' for the array 'highNumbers'");
printf("\n *****************************************");
}

void filterBelowThreshold( int low_limt , int sourceAr[], int 
filtered[])
{
int dex;
for (dex = 0; dex < 100; dex++)
{
    filtered[dex] = -1;
}

int index = 0;
for (dex = 0; dex < 100; dex++)
{
 if(sourceAr[dex] > low_limt)
 {
 filtered[index]= sourceAr[dex];
 index++;
 }
 }
 }

void filterAboveThreshold (int high_limit, int sourceAr[], int 
filtered2[])
{
int dex_2;
for ( dex_2 = 0; dex_2 < 100; dex_2++)
{
filtered2[dex_2] = -1;
}

int index_2 = 0;
for ( dex_2= 0; dex_2 < 100; dex_2++)
{
if(sourceAr[dex_2] < high_limit)
{
filtered2[dex_2] = sourceAr[dex_2];
index_2++;
}
}
}

void print3Arrays(int filterAboveThreshold, int 
filterBelowThreshold, int filtered, int filtered2, int dex , int 
dex_2, int high_limit, int low_limt)
{
printf("\n\n reporting problem findings \n ");
printf("     nums below%d    above%d",low_limt, high_limit);
for (dex = 0; dex < 100; dex++)
{
printf (  "dex %d:  %2d ",dex, sourceAr[dex]);
if (filtered[dex] > 0)
printf("   %2d  ", filtered[dex]);
else
printf("   ---");
if (filtered2[dex_2] > 0)
printf("    %2d\n", filtered2[dex_2]);
else
printf("    ---");
}

}

void terminationScreen()
{
printf("\n *****************************************");
printf("\nprogram terminating...");
printf("\n *****************************************");

}
```

I am just wondering what I might be doing wrong and need some pointers

Comment: Maybe show us code you've tried, and what the errors are?

Comment: *"I've tried different things with multiple errors."*  I see no evidence of that.  Post your code, along with the errors it caused.

Comment: Was having some trouble posting. It's up there now

Comment: Your code does not compile.